# Clear ListView Items and Refresh it in Android

Tags: android, listview

I use internet service to fill a list view. I want to refresh the list view items when user press the refresh button. how can i do this?

In AsyncTask and postExecute i fill the list view:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
        if (jSon.has(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
            String success = jSon.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (success.equals("1")) {

                notes = jSon.getJSONObject("notes");
                for (int i = 0; i < notes.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = notes.getJSONObject(Integer
                            .toString(i));

                    Log.i("JSONObject c >>", c.toString());

                    String id = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_ID);
                    String subject = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_DATE);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(KEY_NOTE_ID, id);
                    map.put(KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT, subject);
                    map.put(KEY_NOTE_DATE, date);

                    noteList.add(map);
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllNotes.this,
                    noteList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                            KEY_NOTE_ID, KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT,
                            KEY_NOTE_DATE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.list_lbl_id, R.id.list_lbl_subject,
                            R.id.list_lbl_date });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you simply call `execute()` again on you AsyncTask?

Comment: @Sam previous items has remain and again appear in listview. for example if in list view i have item1,item2,item3 after the refresh i have item1,item2,item3,item1,item2,item3 in list view.

Comment: Try reinitializing `noteList` or calling `noteList.clear();` in `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: thanks. not need to call notifyChangeSet();?

Comment: I don't believe you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` because `setAdapter()` should do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic approach is to empty `noteList` and run your AsyncTask again.

1. Inside `onPreExecute()` (or the first line of `doInBackground()`) call either:

   ```
   noteList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); // or noteList.clear();
   ```
2. Call your AsyncTask's `execute()` method again.

Also I don't believe you need to use `runOnUiThread()` in `onPostExecute()` because it already has access to the main thread.

Comment: I mean you should be able to create the adapter and call `setAdapter()` in `onPostExecute()` without wrapping it in `runOnUiThread()`. (If your code works you don't have to change anything.)